# First variation of mass

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

**Reference: [this paper page 15](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5511)**

Let $(M,g)$ be a three-manifold and consider a two-sided compact surface $\Sigma \subset M$.

The mass is defined by

$$m(\Sigma) =\ \bigg( \frac{|\Sigma|}{16\pi}  \bigg)^{1/2} 
 \bigg( 1 - \frac{1}{ 16\pi } \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma 
 - \frac{ \Lambda}{24\pi } |\Sigma|  \bigg) \tag{1}$$

where

$\Lambda = \text{inf}_M ~ R$

$R$ is the scalar curvature of $M$.

$H$ is the mean curvature of $\Sigma$.

$K_\Sigma$ is the Gauss curvature of $\Sigma$.

$|\Sigma|$ is the area of $\Sigma$.

The first variation of $m$:

$$\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma(t))\bigg|_{t=0} = - \frac{2|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} \varphi \Delta_\Sigma H d\sigma \\
+ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} \bigg[ 2K_\Sigma - \frac{8\pi}{|\Sigma|  }+ \bigg( \frac{1}{2|\Sigma|}\int_\Sigma H^2 d\sigma - |A|^2 \bigg)   \bigg] H \phi d\sigma \\
+ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_\Sigma (\Lambda - R) H\varphi d\sigma \tag{2}$$

I want to prove (2).

**My Attempt:**

The mass could also be written as

$$m(\Sigma) =\ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{16\pi} \int_\Sigma 2\frac{8\pi}{|\Sigma|} d\sigma  - \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{ 16\pi } \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma 
 - \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{1/2}} \frac{ \Lambda}{24\pi } |\Sigma|  \bigg) \tag{3}$$

$$m(\Sigma) =\ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_\Sigma 2\frac{8\pi}{|\Sigma|} d\sigma  - \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma 
 - \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_\Sigma \frac{2}{3}\Lambda d\sigma  \bigg) \tag{4}$$

Since $\frac{d}{dt}d\sigma = -H\phi d\sigma$, then the first variation becomes

$$\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) =\ - \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_\Sigma 2\frac{8\pi}{|\Sigma|} H\varphi d\sigma  - \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} 2H \frac{dH}{dt} d\sigma \\
+ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} H^2 H\varphi d\sigma
+ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_\Sigma \frac{2}{3}\Lambda H\varphi d\sigma  \bigg) 
\tag{5}$$

Here

$$\frac{dH}{dt}=\Delta\varphi + \text{Ric}(\nu,\nu)\varphi + |A|^2\varphi = \Delta\varphi + \frac{R}{2}\varphi - K_\Sigma\varphi + \frac{H^2}{2}\varphi + \frac{|A|^2}{2}\varphi$$

so that

$$\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) =\ - \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_\Sigma 2\frac{8\pi}{|\Sigma|} H\varphi d\sigma  \\
- \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} 2H \bigg( \Delta\varphi + \frac{R}{2}\varphi - K_\Sigma\varphi + \frac{H^2}{2}\varphi + \frac{|A|^2}{2}\varphi \bigg) d\sigma \\
+ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} H^2 H\varphi d\sigma
+ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_\Sigma \frac{2}{3}\Lambda H\varphi d\sigma  \bigg) 
\tag{6}$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) =\ - \frac{2|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} H\Delta\varphi d\sigma \\
+ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_\Sigma \bigg( 2K_\Sigma - 2\frac{8\pi}{|\Sigma|}\bigg) H\varphi d\sigma  \\
+ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} \bigg( H^2 - H^2 + |A|^2 \bigg)H\varphi d\sigma \\
+ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_\Sigma \bigg( \frac{2}{3}\Lambda - R \bigg) H\varphi d\sigma
\tag{7}$$

which is different from (2).

Did I miss something?

Comment: Ok so now I know where the problem is; I forgot to compute $\frac{d}{dt}|\Sigma_t|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mass could also be written as

\begin{align}
m(\Sigma) =\ \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} 
\bigg( \int_{\Sigma} \frac{16\pi}{|\Sigma|}\ d\sigma -  \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma 
-  \int_{\Sigma} \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda d\sigma  \bigg) 
\end{align}

Since $\frac{d}{dt}|\Sigma_t|=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Sigma}d\sigma = \int_{\Sigma} \frac{d}{dt} d\sigma = - \int_{\Sigma} H\varphi\  d\sigma$, then

\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{dt}|\Sigma|^{1/2}
 =\ & \frac{1}{2}  |\Sigma_t|^{-1/2} \frac{d}{dt}\bigg( |\Sigma_t|  \bigg)
 = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}} \int_{\Sigma} H\varphi\ d\sigma 
\end{align}

also $\frac{d}{dt}d\sigma = -H\phi\ d\sigma$, then we get the first variation of mass

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) 
=\ &\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \frac{|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \bigg) 
 \bigg(  \int_{\Sigma} \frac{16\pi}{|\Sigma|} d\sigma
-  \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma 
-  \int_{\Sigma} \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda d\sigma  \bigg) 
\nonumber\\
& + \frac{|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} 
\frac{d}{dt} \bigg(  1  -  \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma 
-  \int_{\Sigma} \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda d\sigma  \bigg)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) 
=\ & \bigg( -  \frac{1}{(16\pi)^{3/2}|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}} \int_{\Sigma} \frac{1}{2} H\varphi\ d\sigma \bigg)  
\bigg(  \frac{16\pi}{|\Sigma|} |\Sigma|
-   H^2 |\Sigma|
-  \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda |\Sigma|  \bigg)
\nonumber\\
& + \frac{|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} 
\frac{d}{dt} \bigg(  1  -  \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma 
-  \int_{\Sigma} \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda d\sigma  \bigg)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) 
=\ & \bigg( -  \frac{|\Sigma|}{(16\pi)^{3/2}|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}} \int_{\Sigma} \frac{1}{2} H\varphi\ d\sigma \bigg)  
\bigg(  \frac{16\pi}{|\Sigma|}
-   H^2 
-  \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda  \bigg)
\nonumber\\
& + \frac{|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} 
\frac{d}{dt} \bigg(  1  -  \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma 
-  \int_{\Sigma} \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda d\sigma  \bigg)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) 
=\ &  -  \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} \frac{1}{2} \bigg(  \frac{16\pi}{|\Sigma|} -   H^2  -  \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda  \bigg) H\varphi\ d\sigma
\nonumber\\
& + \frac{|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} 
\frac{d}{dt} \bigg(  1  -  \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma 
-  \int_{\Sigma} \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda d\sigma  \bigg)
\end{align}

Now we have

\begin{align}
 &\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( -  \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma \bigg)
 \nonumber\\
 = & - \int_{\Sigma} 2H \frac{dH}{dt} d\sigma 
 + \int_{\Sigma} H^2 H\varphi\ d\sigma
 \nonumber\\
 = & - \int_{\Sigma} 2H \bigg(\Delta\varphi 
 + \frac{R}{2}\varphi - K_\Sigma\varphi + \frac{H^2}{2}\varphi + \frac{|A|^2}{2}\varphi\bigg) d\sigma
 \nonumber\\
 & + \int_{\Sigma} H^2 H\varphi\ d\sigma
 \nonumber\\
 %
 %
 = & - \int_{\Sigma} 2H \Delta\varphi\ d\sigma 
 - \int_{\Sigma} R H\varphi\ d\sigma 
 + \int_{\Sigma} 2K_\Sigma H\varphi\ d\sigma 
 - \int_{\Sigma} H^2 H\varphi\ d\sigma
 - \int_{\Sigma} |A|^2 H\varphi\ d\sigma
 \nonumber\\
 %
 %
 & + \int_{\Sigma} H^2 H\varphi\ d\sigma
 \nonumber\\
 %
 %
 = & - \int_{\Sigma} 2H \Delta\varphi\ d\sigma 
 - \int_{\Sigma} R H\varphi\ d\sigma 
 + \int_{\Sigma} 2K_\Sigma H\varphi\ d\sigma 
 - \int_{\Sigma} |A|^2 H\varphi\ d\sigma
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
 &\frac{d}{dt} \bigg(- \int_{\Sigma} \frac{2}{3} \Lambda d\sigma\bigg)
 \nonumber\\
 %
 %
 = & \int_{\Sigma} \frac{2}{3} \Lambda H\varphi\ d\sigma
\end{align}

Thus, the first derivation becomes

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) 
=\ &  -  \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} \frac{1}{2} \bigg(  \frac{16\pi}{|\Sigma|} -   H^2  -  \frac{ 2}{3 }\Lambda  \bigg) H\varphi\ d\sigma
\nonumber\\
%
%
& + \frac{|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} 
\bigg( - \int_{\Sigma} 2H \Delta\varphi\ d\sigma 
- \int_{\Sigma} R H\varphi\ d\sigma 
+ \int_{\Sigma} 2K_\Sigma H\varphi\ d\sigma 
- \int_{\Sigma} |A|^2 H\varphi\ d\sigma 
\nonumber\\
%
%
& + \int_{\Sigma} \frac{2}{3} \Lambda H\varphi\ d\sigma  \bigg)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) 
=\ &  \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} \bigg(  - \frac{8\pi}{|\Sigma|} +   \frac{1}{2|\Sigma|} \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma  +  \frac{ 1}{3 }\Lambda  \bigg) H\varphi\ d\sigma
\nonumber\\
%
%
& + \frac{|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} 
\bigg( - \int_{\Sigma} 2H \Delta\varphi\ d\sigma 
- \int_{\Sigma} R H\varphi\ d\sigma 
+ \int_{\Sigma} 2K_\Sigma H\varphi\ d\sigma 
- \int_{\Sigma} |A|^2 H\varphi\ d\sigma 
\nonumber\\
%
%
& + \int_{\Sigma} \frac{2}{3} \Lambda H\varphi\ d\sigma  \bigg)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}m(\Sigma) 
=\ &  \frac{|\Sigma|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} \int_{\Sigma} \bigg(  2K_\Sigma - \frac{8\pi}{|\Sigma|} +   \frac{1}{2|\Sigma|} \int_{\Sigma} H^2 d\sigma  - |A|^2 +  \Lambda - R  \bigg) H\varphi\ d\sigma
\nonumber\\
%
%
& - \frac{2|\Sigma_t|^{1/2}}{(16\pi)^{3/2}} 
 \int_{\Sigma} H \Delta\varphi\ d\sigma 
\end{align}

**PROVED.**